# How to store the output from an Objective-C program?

Tags: objective-c

I am developing a small program that generate some numbers randomly and also compute numbers for a high score screen. How do I store both kind of numbers in order to load them later when I re-start the program?

Comment: Store in a DB or write to a file :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the followings to store data

- NSUserDefaults
- PList
- CoreData
- SQLite

Here is link for tutorials http://doganberktas.com/2010/10/16/data-storage-alternatives-on-ios-in-a-nutshell/

Answer (score 0):

I use UltraLite Database to store data on Mobile devices. If that's something you are trying to accomplish. You might what to check it out.

Read the .pdf here:
http://download.sybase.com/pdfdocs/awg0900e/ulfoen9.pdf